# How to use DateFormatter for create current date with Date type?

Tags: ios, swift, date

I have code like this:

```
func getCurrentDate() -> Date {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.medium
    formatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.none
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "GMT")

    //I want for currentDate would be a Date type
    let currentDate = formatter... /// how to convert to date type?
    return currentDate
}
```

How to return formatted current date? Date function return date in this format: 2019-02-24 12:04:13 +0000. But I want to get date in that format: 24.02.2019.

I need a Date type for this code:

```
let differenceOfDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents(Set<Calendar.Component>([.day]),
                                                                  from: getDateFromString(foodDate: getCurrentDateString()),
                                                                  to: foodShelfLife).day
```

In that code I get String date and convert it to Date type! I want to get Date type in 1 function.

Comment: If you want current date and your func return type is `Date` then why do you need a formatter? Current date is `Date()` so you don’t even need a function for it.

Comment: Current date is `Date()` no matter what is the format. You should get a date and display it in the appropriate format.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson no, current date have format like this: 2019-02-24 12:04:13 +0000. I want to format like this: 24.02.2019

Comment: But your function returns a Date so the format is irrelevant since a Date is not formatted, you format your date when you convert it to a string.

Comment: And why do you need to call `getDateFromString`, does it alter the date in any way before converting it?

Comment: Note that date format is not localized properly in any language. Please dont format dates like that.

Comment: Either use `dateStyle / timeStyle` **or** `dateFormat`, never both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not call the calendar function like this

```
let differenceOfDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents(Set<Calendar.Component>([.day]),
                                                              from: Date(),
                                                              to: foodShelfLife).day
```

---

*Old solution*

You need to change your func to return a String (or perform the formatting at a later stage)

```
func getCurrentDate() -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy”
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_POSIX_US")

    return formatter.string(from: Date())
 }
```

Comment: this is wrong you should NOT use dateFormat at the same time as the date/time style.

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks. I admit I just copied the code without looking at it to much .

Comment: Note also when parsing fixed date formats you need to set the locale to en_US_POSIX

Answer (score 2):

If I am not mistaking, there is a misunderstanding here.

Date has nothing to do with how to display it (the format). Mentioning that:

> Date function return date in this format: 2019-02-24 12:04:13 +0000.

is the result of printing `Date()`:

```
print(Date())
```

If you want to see it as "24.02.2019", then you should edit its format, therefore `getCurrentDate` should return a string instead:

```
func getCurrentDate() -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.medium
    formatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.none
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "GMT")

    let currentDate = formatter.string(from: Date())
    return currentDate
}
```

Therefore:

```
print(getCurrentDate())
```

should give you the result of `24.02.2019`.

---

**Update:**

If you are aiming to work with `dateComponents`, you should deal with dates without caring about formatting them. Example:

```
let yesterday = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: Date())!
let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents(Set<Calendar.Component>([.day]), from: yesterday, to: Date())
print(components) // day: 1 isLeapMonth: false
```

Comment: Yes, I know it, I want to use current date with Date type for another function. I need a Date.

Comment: @Tkas is there an issue with `let differenceOfDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents(Set<Calendar.Component>([.day]),
                                                                  from: getDateFromString(foodDate: Date()),
                                                                  to: foodShelfLife).day`? I mean you should be able to pass `Date()` directly as a date then.

Comment: this is wrong you should NOT use dateFormat at the same time as the date/time style.

Comment: @LeoDabus Thank you for your kind comment, would you please elaborate?